# bash 4.3 "multiple dot" commands fails silently on Fedora

Tags: bash, fedora

I just noted this on bash  4.3; exact version number is 4.3.42(1)-release (x86-redhat-linux-gnu).

```
$ ..
$ ...
$ ....
$ .....
```

Why do the "command not found" is not prompted ?

```
$ ...
$ echo $? 
$ 127
```

I checked the `$PATH` and the `alias` nothing; The man is not helping neither.
The bash run on Fedora Linux, but I think it is not related to the OS.

**EDIT**

I just noted this it the same for any dot starting command

```
.za
.zaza
..za
..zaza
```

Comment: When you do that do you get any response at all?

Comment: @John Yes it is like I posted here. On my computers I traditionally alias "..." to `sudo -s` here I forgot to do so, this is how I discovered it.

Comment: Works as expected on Debian 4.3.42(1)-release. Do you have a `command_not_found_handle` function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was caused by the command-not-found handling in Fedora.

Running an unknown command (including `...` etc. if no alias matches) causes `command_not_found_handle` to be run with the missing command as parameter (see `/etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh` for its definition). In the given scenario, the handler then runs `/usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found`, again with the missing command as parameter. Previously, `pk-command-not-found` simply [ignored any command starting with `.`](https://github.com/hughsie/PackageKit/blob/master/contrib/command-not-found/pk-command-not-found.c#L808):

```
if (argv[1][0] == '.')
    goto out;
```

and exited with code 127.

This behaviour was [introduced](https://github.com/hughsie/PackageKit/commit/0e85001b) to fix [Red Hat #1151185](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1151185), is also referenced in [Bash does not print any error msg upon non-existing commands starting with dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309107/bash-does-not-print-any-error-msg-upon-non-existing-commands-starting-with-dot), and has a bug requesting a fix ([Red Hat #1292531](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1292531)). It’s largely been fixed in FC 27 with updates, since PackageKit 1.1.8 (see [this commit](https://github.com/hughsie/PackageKit/commit/d3533878038ebdcf6ae2b3524c8c8e2f1b47e84b)): now commands with leading dots are processed, only `.` and `..` are ignored.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will consider to use a different shell.

Comment: @Emmanuel or you could just disable Fedora's broken command-not-found handler with something like  `unset -f command_not_found_handle` in your ~/.bashrc.   Or uninstall whatever Fedora package is providing the command-not-found functionality (on debian, I run `apt-get purge command-not-found` on every debian box i build.  I do the same for the `bash-completion` package.  Both are far more annoying than any benefit they bring)

Comment: Note that whatever this bug was, it's fixed now.

Comment: @StephenKitt Hmmm, weird. Not on mine. I get "command not found" in most of the example cases, and additionally `Similar command is: '..'` with `...`.

Comment: Actually, following your github link in your answer now shows fixed code. [This commit](https://github.com/hughsie/PackageKit/commit/d3533878038ebdcf6ae2b3524c8c8e2f1b47e84b) from two months ago did it — instead of just looking for a starting `.`, it checks explicitly for `.` and `..`.

Comment: Right @mattdm, thanks; that also explains why [`..` still runs silently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419475/86440). I’ll update the answer and the bug...