# In bash why does the command .. not produce any error text

Tags: bash

Using bash, if I enter the command `..` I get no text output to indicate that the command failed or could not be found, although the error code 127 is returned.
However if I issue any other command that doesn't exist, e.g. ooo I see this printed

```
bash: ooo: command not found...
```

with a return code of 127

Why does this inconsistency happen?

Further investigation reveals that
`type -a ..` bash can not find that command `bash: type: ..: not found`

`(set -x ;..)` shows something is running?

```
 + ..
 + local runcnf=1
 + local retval=127
 + [[ himxBHs == *\i* ]]
 + [[ ! -S /run/dbus/system_bus_socket ]]
 + [[ ! -x /usr/libexec/packagekitd ]]
 + [[ -n '' ]]
 + [[ ! -x /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found ]]
 + '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
 + /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found ..
 + retval=127
 + return 127
```

`ls -ld` is a directory `drwxr-xr-x. 12 wilhadden wilhadden 4096 Oct 18 14:55 ..`

`...` does produce output `bash: ...: command not found...` -
Jeff Schaller

Comment: Investigate with `type -a ..`.

Comment: I see `bash: type: ..: not found`

Comment: `..` is the link to the parent of your current directory.  Further investigate: `(set -x ;..)`. Also look at `ls -ld ..`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Sounds like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282996/117549

Comment: Jeff - it's very similar but anything other than .. will produce error text

Comment: Jeff - you're correct the answer there explains the behaviour I'm seeing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283005/592740

A fix went in to /usr/libexec/packagekitd which now ignores `.` and `..`